# How do I stop a table from disappearing under a Heading?

Tags: microsoft-word, table-styles

I am building a guide using headings so that I can collapse heading to show just the steps (Quick Guide) or expand the headings to show details & screenshots (Comprehensive Guide).

I have inserted a table into the document, but I have tried setting the style to Heading2 (same as the text) but when I collapse all headings, the table is hidden under Heading.

How to keep the table visible please?

Picture of text and table:
[image: Table & text]

Answer (score 0):

1. Body Text should NOT be in a heading style. This defeats the whole idea of using heading styles.
2. If you collapse all headings you will collapse anything between headings even if placed in text boxes or Frames.

### If you place your table before any heading level text, and it is not, itself, in a heading style, it will not be collapsed.

If your table is in the Heading 1 style, it will not be collapsed, but this violates principle #1 above.

Body text can be formatted to look like headings and headings can be formatted to look like body text.